# How to draw a point on a border of a rectangle?

Tags: java, vector, trigonometry, processing

I am breaking my neck trying to solve this... 
The point should be located on border at place where mouse is pointing. In other words on crossing between rectangle borderline and a line between rectangle center and mouse pointer. I need to use trigonometry somehow as rectangle might be rotating. Below code (in processing) enables me to draw point but only on south border...

```
int size = 200;

void setup() {
  size(1200,500);
  smooth();
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  rectMode(CENTER);

}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  noFill();

  PVector center = new PVector(width/2,height/2);
  PVector mouse = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);

  float mouseDistance = PVector.dist(center,mouse);

  mouse.sub(center); // mouse coordinates relative to center point

  float t = atan2(mouse.y, mouse.x);

  float borderDistance = (size/2) / sin(t); 
  float bx = cos(t) * borderDistance;
  float by = sin(t) * borderDistance;

  pushMatrix();
    translate(center.x, center.y);
    strokeWeight(5);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    point(0,0);
    point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    point(cos(t)*size/2, sin(t)*size/2);
    point(bx,by);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(0, 0, size, size);
    rect(0,0, size, size);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    line(0, 0, mouse.x, mouse.y);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay here's the math that will be involved to give you the location of your desired point.

Diagram for reference:

[image: Problem Diagram]

To find the `Green` point, all we need to do is find the find the height and the width of the imaginary rectangle (see image), which are labeled as `Adj` and `Opp` respectively, and add those values to the `Center` point.

---

If you remember `SOH CAH TOA`, we'll leverage `TOA`:

```
Tan(Theta) = Opposite / Adjacent
```

which can be re-arranged to:

```
Opposite = Tan(Theta) * Adjacent
```

So we'll need to first find `Adjacent (Adj)` and `Theta`.

---

Consulting the diagram, `Adj` is obviously the difference in `y` between `Orange` and `Center`:

```
Adj = Orange.y - Center.y
```

But we don't know `Orange`?  Well, `Orange` would be equal to `Center` plus half the height of the rectangle:

```
Orange = (Center.x, Center.y + Rect.Height/2)
```

Subbing the value of `Orange` back into our `Adj` calculation:

```
Adj = Center.y + Rect.Height/2 - Center.y
Adj = Rect.Height/2
```

---

Next we need to find `Theta`.

[image]

Rerfering back to `SOH CAH TOA` `CAH`:

```
Cos(Theta) = Adjacent / Hypotenuse
Theta = acos(Adjacent / Hypotenuse)  //Inverse cosine
```

We already know that `Adj = Rect.Height/2` from earlier, so we just need to find `Hyp`.  To find `Hyp` we can use the [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) which says:

```
d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
```

In our case:

```
Hyp = sqrt((Center.x - Mouse.x)^2 + (Center.y - Mouse.y)^2)
```

So now we have everything we need for `Theta`:

```
Theta = acos(Adj / Hyp)  //Inverse cosine
```

---

Finally, we have what we need for `Opp`:

```
Opp = Tan(Theta) * Adjacent
```

Which means we have everything we need to answer your question:

```
Green = (Center.x + Opp, Center.y + Adj)
```

---

Notes:

- This is the "on paper math" using degrees.  A lot of programming languages deal with radians instead of degrees, so you may have to do some converting.
- As @Jerry Andrews pointed out, there will be four different cases to this problem, which correspond to the four different sides of the rectangle that your drawing point could fall on:

> To determine the quadrant, he first needs the angle between the center
>   of the rectangle and any corner--thus, atan(height/width). This will
>   give the half-angle (center-to-green, if green is on a corner). Then
>   atan(mouse.y/mouse.x) will provide the angle of the line from the
>   rectangle center to the mouse cursor (because in his code, the mouse
>   is located relative to the center of the rectangle).

Comment: +1 for awesome diagrams. Note that the response might differ if the mouse was, say, to the left of the rectangle, so the segment intersects the west wall rather than the south wall... he's going to have to figure out which wall he's hitting for a completely general answer.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point.  Also to the OP: I'm just testing this out now, hopefully I remembered everything correctly from HighSchool :)

Comment: To determine the quadrant, he first needs the angle between the center of the rectangle and any corner--thus, atan(height/width). This will give the half-angle (center-to-green, if green is on a corner).  Then atan(mouse.y/mouse.x) will provide the angle of the line from the rectangle center to the mouse cursor (because in his code, the mouse is located relative to the center of the rectangle). Finally, there are 4 variations of your solution, one for each quadrant.

Comment: @ Jerry i am stuck exactly on determining the right quadrant... max `adjacent` is `d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)` so perhaps adding conditional `if( tan(t)*adj > d ) { /* some magic code here switching phase from horizontal to vertical */ }`  ?

Answer (score 0):

OK! i have managed to solve the point on border issue. processing sketch and code available under [this link](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/138410)

I used atan2() function to calculate mouseTheta and then needed to play with quadrants:

```
 // north
      borderPoint = new PVector(tan(mouseTheta-HALF_PI)*r, -r);
 // east
      if(mouseTheta > TWO_PI-QUARTER_PI || mouseTheta < QUARTER_PI) 
         borderPoint = new PVector(r, tan(mouseTheta)*r);
 // south
      if(mouseTheta >= QUARTER_PI && mouseTheta < QUARTER_PI+HALF_PI) 
         borderPoint = new PVector(-tan(mouseTheta-HALF_PI)*r, r); 
 // west
      if(mouseTheta >= HALF_PI+QUARTER_PI && mouseTheta < PI+QUARTER_PI) 
         borderPoint = new PVector(-r,-tan(mouseTheta)*r);
```

looks ugly but works... thanks!